# Angular browser version returns value as null when URL is called

Tags: javascript, angular

Facebook wants to check out my privacy page that i put in the developers dashboard. So far so good. Now in the mysite.com/privacy i am calling a variable that is set from home page (mysite.com) so when they hit on their browser the privacy page (mysite.com/privacy) without visiting first the home page (mysite.com) then obviously the value is not set.

this is the error i am getting

```
  ERROR TypeError: ctx.userDetails is null
MainHeaderComponent_Template template.html:9
```

.html page
<div class="login-header-block" *ngIf="userDetails.username!='guest'">

.ts page

```
constructor(
private userData: UserData,
private router: Router,
private alertCtrl: AlertController,
  ) { 

this.userDetails = this.userData.getUserData();
this.getNotifications();
}
```

I want to be able to keep the ngIf but i want it to show the page without errors

any help

Comment: yes it is undefined only because they hit the ecaxt URL (mysite.com/privacy) if one goes from root page (mysite.com) i set the value for userdetails when the privacy link is pressed the exact URL is rovespier.com You may see what i mean First type in rovespier.com/privacy it will show the page blank. But if you first go to rovespier.com and press the privacy link it will show the page as wanted. Can you show me an exampe of what you mean?

Comment: Why not create a router guard that checks whether the `userDetails` exist before routing the user to /privacy page and if `userDetails` is undefined route the user to the homepage even if /privacy route is hit externally? Also, if I am understanding your question right, you basically want to set a default value for `userDetails.username` if userDetails is undefined, is that correct?